# What's with the Jem Hadar unique names?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

And I do not mean "Jem'Hadar first", "Jem'Hadar second", and so on.

I mean these: Remata'Klan, Ikat'ika, Ixtana'Rax, Kudak'Etan

Jem'Hadar do not have parents, they are created in birthing chambers. I looked up a list of all the named Jem'Hadar characters and none appear to share the same name or part of it. There is only one Remata'Klan who's name end with 'Klan. Also while I write this it is very irritating putting the ' between the names everytime. So what's the ' for anyway?

While you call every soldier under your command first, second, third and so on, why give them such unique names?

I can only come up with the following: First of all giving them numbers all the time, might resemble them too much like Borg drones. 
Second, stating that they are born within birthing chambers, I could guess that either the first part or the second part might be named after their birthing chamber. This would make Remata'Klan "brothers" with Remata' kling* or Yesler'Klan. (Both names I just made up.) During the early nineties there was a cartoon called Exosquad where humans created the Neo Sapiens, also from something that remebled birthing chambers. Those who were created in the same chamber were considers brothers.

Also since the Jem'Hadar were created by the Founders and the founders also enhanced the Vorta somewhere in history, can we assume the Jem'Hadar names are part of the founders language?
"Remata" could mean "thunder" and "'Klan"  could mean "strike"?

Answer (score 3):

> While you call every soldier under your command first, second, third and so on, why give them such unique names?

First, Second, Third, et al. are not names, they're ranks and positions. They can change. In 6x02 "Rocks and Shoals", part of the tension between Third Remata'Klan and his vorta Keevan is that Remata'Klan was not elevated to First when the previous First and Second were killed, as would normally be the case.

Too, the Jem'Hadar are living, thinking individuals. They learn and grow through experience just like humans do, so it's natural to imagine that not all of them are equally adept at every task. It would be valuable to the Dominion to be able to shuffle troops around to positions at which they show greater aptitude, or to shore up the weaknesses in a unit that's suffered casualties.

Because a Jem'Hadar's unit and position can change, they need a way of identifying individuals that won't be constantly reset by reassignments or filling vacant ranks. Hence, personal names.

It's worth noting that, unlike Borg drones, Jem'Hadar *are* individuals. Compare for instance Captain Picard's interactions with Hugh and Captain Sisko's with Remata'Klan. To Hugh, the concept that he has an individual choice separate from the will of the collective is foreign and intrusive. Remata'Klan in constrast acknowledges that he *could* abandon Keevan, and argues why it would be wrong for him to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe an in-universe explanation existed when named Jem'Hadar first appeared, and I don't recall any on-screen canon that would offer an explanation. If an explanation exists now, it would most certainly have been ret-conned via later works.

As to why a Jem'Hadar would have been named, there is a simple explanation from a story-writing perspective - it "humanizes" the character. As to the system of naming, I don't believe it was entirely thought through. Most of the Federation interaction with Jem'Hadar occurs at the level of space battles or troop combat. There is no sense of an individual Jem'Hadar having any "personality" beyond forced loyalty to the dispenser of its Ketracel white, blind obedience up the chain of command and equally blind reverence to the founders. In the stories where we know a Jem'Hadar by name, there are conversations through which we find a bit more dimension to those characters, along with identifiable motives and some semblance of an emotional structure. Having a name helps us believe the character has those aspects of humanity, despite all the brutality.